# iPad SplitViewController Show Popover programmatically

Tags: ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, uipopovercontroller

I have an iPad SplitViewController application in which I hide the left pane in both portrait and landscape modes.  I need to show the left pane in its popover when a certain notification is received by the application.  Despite experimenting with a number of different suggested solutions I am struggling to work out how to achieve this.

I am using a MultipleMasterDetailManager implementation that includes the following code:

```
/* forward the message to the current detail view
 * all detail views must implement UISplitViewControllerDelegate
 */
-(void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem forPopoverController:(UIPopoverController *)pc
{
    self.masterBarButtonItem = barButtonItem;
    self.masterPopoverController = pc;

    barButtonItem.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Show Sidebar", @"Show Sidebar");

    [self.currentDetailController.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:self.masterBarButtonItem animated:YES];
}

/* forward the message to the current detail view
 * all detail views must implement UISplitViewControllerDelegate
 */
-(void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController invalidatingBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem
{
    //if (![self.currentDetailController isKindOfClass:[SyncSourceDetailViewController class]])
    //{
        self.masterBarButtonItem = nil;
        self.masterPopoverController = nil;

        [self.currentDetailController.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:nil animated:YES];    
    //}    
}
```

Similar methods exist in the detail view controllers themselves.

The method that I'm calling when the notification is received is as follows:

```
- (void)navigateToLatest 
{   
        [self navigateToDocumentsTab];  
        [[self dataLoader] navigateToLatest];  // populates data for the left table view 
        UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
        UIView *view = [[[[[splitViewController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:1] viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0] view];  

        [self.masterDetailManager.masterPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100) inView:view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
}
```

This does not work.  I've also tried using the presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem method but I cannot seem to locate the leftBarButtonItem in code.

Maybe I am going about this completely the wrong way.

Comment: This view: `UIView *view = [[[[[splitViewController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:1] viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0] view];` is this really the parent view you want to use?

Comment: @slf - you are correct, I have been continuing to work on this and I have determined that the view that I need is:  self.masterDetailManager.currentDetailController.view.  However this still does not work - I have a feeling it is to do with timing as the leftBarButtonItem for this view does not exist at this point in time, also willHideViewController in the masterDetailManager is called subsequent to my navigateToLatest method.

Comment: @slf - I have been able to get showing of the left pane to work from a BarButtonItem using similar code so I know I am not too far away.  Maybe I need to be delaying the call to show the left pane in some way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up solving this problem by setting a "showSidebar" variable in my app delegate to true in the navigateToLatest method. Then in my DetailViewController's ViewDidAppear event I check the value of this variable, if it is true then I show the sidebar using the following code:

```
UIPopoverController *masterPopoverController= [[theAppDelegate masterDetailManager] masterPopoverController];
        [masterPopoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:[self.navigationItem leftBarButtonItem] permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
        [theAppDelegate setShowSidebar:NO];
```